# Operations research versus statistical analysis?

Tags: operations-research

What is the difference between operations research and statistical analysis?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are entire academic discplines so I do not think you can expect much more here than pointers to further, and more extensive, documentation as e.g. Wikipedia on [Operations Research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research) and [Statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics).

Let me try a personal definition which may be grossly simplifying:

- Operations Research is concerned with process modeling and optimisation
- Statistical Modeling is concerning with describing the so-called 'data generating process': find a model that describes something observed, and then do estimation, inference and possibly prediction.

Answer (score 11):

Operations Research (OR), sometimes called "Management Science", consists of three main topics, Optimization, Stochastic Processes, Process and Production Methodologies.

OR uses statistical analysis in many contexts (for example discrete event simulations) but they should not be considered the same, additionally one of the main topics in OR is optimization (linear, and nonlinear) which can make it more clear why these two fields should be considered different

There is [another exchange website for OR](http://www.or-exchange.com/questions) if you are interested

Answer (score 7):

Operations Research began during wartime in the 1940s with scientists and others addressing problems in Radar operations, Anti-Submarine Warfare (ASW), and air operations. It is really a methodology to help decision makers choose a course of action by using an analytic framework that includes statistics, linear and non-linear programming, game theory, decision theory, etc. Statistics is one of many tools it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Operation research is the process for optimizing the problem to analyse some near value and we get different answers in Transportation method in OR.

Statistics is the process of collection, presentation, analysis, and interpretation of data. We use random number generation in operation research, simulation model.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user39491. I do not completely follow this. Could you clarify & elaborate your points?